# Who was the woman signing books in The End of Time?

Tags: doctor-who

In *The End of Time: Part 2*, who was the woman signing books? More specifically, who was her grandmother?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The lady who was signing books, played by Jessica Hynes, is **Verity Newman**. She’s the granddaughter of Joan Redfern, the Doctor’s romantic companion in the season 3 two-parter *Human Nature/The Family of Blood*.

She’s explaining her book to another customer, which lines up with Redfern. And it seems pretty clear that’s who the Doctor was asking about:

> **Verity:** No, it’s not just a story, no. Every word of it’s true. I found my great grandmother’s diary in the loft. And she was a nurse in 1913. She fell in love with this man called John Smith. Except he was a visitor. From another world. She fell in love with a man from the stars. And she wrote it all down. {Signing the next book} And who’s it for?
>
> **The Doctor:** The Doctor.
>
> **Verity:** “To The Doctor”. Funny. That’s the name he used.
>
> **The Doctor:** Was she happy? In the end?
>
> **Verity:** Yes. Yes she was. Were you?

In addition, the cover of the book resembles Gallifreyan writing and the fob watch. Not a perfect match, but you can clearly see the resemblance:

[image]

Comment: fun fact: The name Verity Newman was an homage to two of the people most responsible for *Doctor Who*: Sydney Newman (who created *Doctor Who*) and Verity Lambert (who produced the first two series)

Comment: Nitpick: not the Doctor's romantic companion, John Smith's. (It might seem like a minor point, but was actually quite an important one in *The Family of Blood*.)